# Geopandas: Error trying to create shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, create

I am attempting to create a shapefile for an attribute that I will be using in a model. The code works up until I get to creating the shapefile and then I receive this error:

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'.

Here is my code

This loads the neighborhoods shapefile, attribute shapefile, joins them, then aggregates based on a count, and then attempts to create a shapefile. The last line is where I get the error. Any ideas?

```
submarket_shp = gpd.read_file("/Users/chrismcmanus/Desktop/DSBA 6400 - Internship/submarkets_shp-2/submarkets.shp")
submarket_shp= submarket_shp.to_crs("EPSG:4269") # NAD83
submarket_shp = submarket_shp.rename(columns={"Id": "ID"}) ## rename columns

## medical facilities shp
mf_shp = gpd.read_file("/Users/chrismcmanus/Desktop/DSBA 6400 - Internship/medicalfacilities-3/MedicalFacilities.shp")
mf_shp = mf_shp.to_crs("EPSG:4269") # NAD83

#Spatial Join the medical facilities and the submarket 
mf_submarkets_join = gpd.sjoin(submarket_shp, mf_shp, how="inner", op="intersects")

## aggregate based on mf in submarket
mf_submarkets_join_agg = mf_submarkets_join.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).agg(['count'])
mf_shp = pd.merge(submarket_shp, mf_submarkets_join_agg, on=['ID'] , how="outer")
mf_shp.to_file("mf.shp")
```

Comment: @BERA mf_shp.to_file("mf.shp")

Comment: Try to remove the square brackets from ID field at the groupby and at the merge functions.  Also after groupby you can simply call .count() instead of .agg(['count'])

Comment: @Ofir it would be mf_submarkets_join_agg = mf_submarkets_join.groupby('ID', as_index=False).count()?

Comment: @BERA I still get the same error changing it to mf_shp.to_file("mf.gpkg")

Comment: @Ofir I get a new error TypeError: Cannot interpret '<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype object at 0x7fb880e25f10>' as a data type when trying to save the file in mf_shp.to_file("mf.shp")

Comment: Can you check if the variable mf_shp is not empty or has missing geometry value?